# In Linq to Sql How to get all the foreign key fields for an entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I'd like to get all the Foreign Key columns in a Table in my entity.
For example:

```
class User
{
    Id {get;set;}
    Name {get;set;}
    ColumnWithForeignKey1Id{get;set;}
    ColumnWithForeignKey2Id{get;set;}        
    ColumnWithForeignKey3Id{get;set;}
}
```

result should be like:

- ColumnWithForeignKey1Id
- ColumnWithForeignKey2Id
- ColumnWithForeignKey3Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example, to gather the ForeignKeys defined with a special attribute; for this question "AssociationAttribute" and inside a given class, for this example "ClassName".

Thanks for `David B` for the guidance.

```
public void Get<TAttribute>(object obj, bool inherit) where TAttribute : System.Attribute
{
     var ForeignKeyCollection = typeof(ClassName).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), true).Any())
                .Select(p => new
                                 {
                                     Property = p,
                                     Attribute = (AssociationAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(TAttribute), true)
                                 })
                .Where(p => p.Attribute.IsForeignKey).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your dbml file in an xml editor and you'll see foreign keys:

```
  <Association Name="Table1_Table2" Member="Table1" ThisKey="Table2ID" OtherKey="ID" Type="Table2" IsForeignKey="true" />
```

Open the designer.cs file and you'll see foreign keys implemented as a property that has a `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute` which is backed by either an `EntityRef` or `EntitySet`.

If you're using reflection, look for `AssociationAttribute`.

---

If you aren't using the designer to generate the modeling classes, decorate those properties with your own attribute so you can find them.

Comment: I actually don't know how to gather the foreign keys even if they have this attribute, I mean from code behind. thanks

Comment: Here's a link to a simple reflection example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379.aspx

Comment: Yes this was the answer. I will post an example here, I hope you can update the answer with that example; thanks.