# Transfer a record and all dependent data from one SQL Server to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 servers running SQL Server 2008 Express. Both servers host a structural identical database (same table structure). Each database contains different customer data. 
Now I need to move one customer from one server to the other.
Copying the record from the customer table would be easy, but there are about 50 more tables with dependent data (foreign key ralations) that I need to copy as well.

Is there any tool that is able to detect the dependancies and export / import the data accordingly?

I have also started to code the export in C# myself. Problem here is that I haven't found a way yet to detect dependencies dynamically. Therefore it would be a static export and I would need to adjust it every time the database structure changes.
Any hint here would also be very helpful. (VS 2010 .net 4.0)

Comment: Entity Framework may help out if you're set on using c#. The best solution may be writing a SQL script to do the export.

Comment: I am using Linq to SQL in C# but I have not found a way to get related tables dynamically. A SQL script would be most likly too complex and too long to handle it savely.

Comment: Try setting lazy load to false (Google). Make sure there are actual foreign key relationships on the tables so EF knows how all the tables are related.

Comment: Use Entity Framework, database first, and create a new Entity Data Model and point it to your database. If the relationships are all setup correctly, EF will create all the classes (like Customer) and all its related classes.

Comment: Seems Reflection is the only way to get this done, the best starting point so far was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421200/in-linq-to-sql-how-to-get-all-the-foreign-key-fields-for-an-entity . I just had hoped to find a more simple solution

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use some kind of `ORM`. That way you can easily find dependents. Then you should move hole family at a time.

Let me know if you have question.

Comment: You're referencing something like LINQ to SQL?  
Linq knows realations but I have not found a way to get it dynamically. A quick search on other ORM brought up NHibernate for C# but it looks like a monster.

Comment: See this:http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx I don't know if there is something easier than using entity framework for your job.

Comment: Let me know if you don't know what is EF.

Comment: LINQ to SQL, Telerik ORM, NHibernate, ADO.NET entity framework, are all quite similar to eachother. I am used to LINQ to SQL. The 'simple' problem is that I need to get tables related to eachother by foreign key constraints. Something like customers.GetRelatedTables().

Comment: If you use EF you could find relatives of that object. if you want to do this dynamically then use Reflection.